# How to call a field on same condition

Tags: sqlite, pascalscript

If I have two different table with same field name like

Table A have below Field.

```
field 1. Serial
field 2. FName
field 3. MName
Field 4. LName
```

and table B also have only the one same field.

```
field 1. Serial
Calculate field. Full Name
```

I want to make a calculated field for full name which recall

```
SELECT FName || MName || LName From Table A When ID=Serial
```

mean by putting Serial # call full name in calculated field

If I put the Serial 1 and calculated field called Peter etc.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us _exact_ sample data for both tables.  Don't add prefixes or anything else to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CUDA12, He really Solve my Problem. I got my Solution.

```
sqlite> SELECT Table A.Serial, Table A.FNAME, Table A.MName, Table A.LName, Table B.Serial
    FROM Table A AS A, Table B AS B
    WHERE  Table A.Serial = B.Serial;
```